# Why does Visual Studio Code display some emojis wrong?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, unicode, terminal

I am trying to print different emojis in python using visual studio code. However, when I print some emojis (just using print()) some (not all) emojis get displayed using the wrong width, more specifically if a character is printed next to it it will over lap the emoji. This will make more sense visually:

For some emojis its perfectly fine:
`print("")` |
[image: Emojis that work]

However for others this happens:
`print("")` |
[image: Emojis that show incorrectly]

That's a log emoji (though it happens to many others as well), the face emoji overlaps the log emoji because vs-code doesn't give it the correct width (I'm pretty sure all emojis are twice as wide as a normal alphabetic character). This only happens in the Terminal not in the editor.
I have absolutely no idea why this happens for only some emojis
I have tried changing the font but it has absolutely no effect.

Not sure if this is helpful but I was previously using a different code editor where all emojis where displayed incorrectly i.e. Not being recognised as larger than a normal char however in that code editor all emojis where displayed that way so I just added a space after every emoji to stop them overlapping however in vs code only some are incorrect.
(Adding spaces to just some emojis is very inconvenient and I don't see why this should be an issue in the first place)

If I try this in command prompt by typing python and then `print("")` it works fine, so I believe it is specifically an issue with VS Code's integrated terminal.

EDIT:  I am using the latest version of vs code (1.78.0) and the latest version of python (3.11.3) and yes I am using windows. I would like to clarify what I mean by the vs code terminal, here is an image: ibb.co/J7tMCZX this issue is specific to running code inside the visual studio code application, If I open a command prompt window and navigate to the file path and type "python test.py" to run the file I get no issues.

Comment: What happens if you run this code in PowerShell, cmd or WSL? Try each of these inside VS Code and outside it. I suspect this has to do with the terminal and not specifically with VS Code.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue in VS Code's integrated terminal with version 1.78.0 of VS Code with Python 3.10.6 on Ubuntu 22.04.1. It doesn't happen if I run the `print` in an interactive python prompt, or if I run a file containing the `print`. What versions of these things do you have installed? And just to confirm, you are on Windows, correct?

Comment: but what I see doesn't match what you see, which why you should provide as much info about your system and setup as possible (including the info I asked about above).

Comment: I assume your results depend on what version of wcswidth is being used, and what version of Unicode it supports. It is important to note that if the emoji is from an unsupported version of Unicode, the width will be wrong. It is also important to note that some emoji default to text presentation rather than emoji presentation, so will have width if 1 instead of 2. Also, it only really works with simple emoji. Take the emoji ‍❤️‍‍, with an ideal font, it is a single emoji glyph. Its length is 10 characters, making one grapheme, and wcswidth reports a width of 7.

Comment: @Andj can you reproduce the behaviour reported in the question here? I cannot so I'm curious if you can. I get the laughing emoji printed first with a width of 2, then the wood emoji to the right of the laughing emoji with a width of 1. I'm on VS Code 1.78.1 now.

Comment: I suspect it depends on what operating system is used. I am on 1.77.3 on macOS and no problems with the emoji in itErm2, Terminal or VS Code integrated terminal. But complex emoji are problematic.

Comment: TP_Horror, you showed `print("")` but then showed a screenshot where the log gets printed to the left of the laughing emoji. Is that screenshot really the result of that code? Or did you get that screenshot from running `print("")`? Because when I run `print("")` on my Windows 11 machine, I get what is shown in your screenshot, but not when I run `print("")`.

Comment: One point worth noting, the functions used to identify width of emoji is dependent on the version of Unicode supported. For instance,  was defined in Unicode 13 so any function built on Unicode 13+ data would identify a width of 2. And function using data prior to Unicode 13 will generate a width of 1.

Comment: Did you make sure of the content of the string, *code point by code point*? Maybe it contains some unexpected zero-width joiners or something. I mean, what I copied and pasted out of the question doesn't, but maybe that got messed up somewhere in the process of pasting into the question.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this issue in VS Code's integrated terminal with version 1.78.0 of VS Code with Python 3.10.6 on Ubuntu 22.04.1. It doesn't happen if I run the `print` in an interactive python prompt, or if I run a file containing the print.

But what I ***can*** do is shed light on how glyph widths are *supposed* to work in VS Code's integrated terminal:

VS Code uses xtermjs to implement its integrated terminal. Mini rabbit hole: google "`github xterm.js issues some emoji take up one character width instead of two`" -> https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/issues/1059 -> https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/issues/1709 -> https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/pull/2568/files -> https://github.com/jerch/xterm.js/blob/master/src/common/input/UnicodeV6.ts#L88, which is the file in xterm.js that determines what width to give to glyphs. It would be a bit ridiculous for me to paste the whole file here, but here's a little window into what's going on in there (see the full file for all the context):

> ```js
> public wcwidth(num: number): CharWidth {
>   if (num < 32) return 0;
>   if (num < 127) return 1;
>   if (num < 65536) return table[num] as CharWidth;
>   if (bisearch(num, HIGH_COMBINING)) return 0;
>   if ((num >= 0x20000 && num <= 0x2fffd) || (num >= 0x30000 && num <= 0x3fffd)) return 2;
>   return 1;
> }
> ```

The wood emoji is `0x1FAB5` (decimal: 129717), which as far as I can tell from visual inspection, doesn't match any of the `if` blocks, and hits the final `return 1;` in `wcwidth`, which matches the behaviour I see in my integrated terminal.

Also note that a lot of terminal emulators have varying behaviours with emoji width that some find confusing or frustrating. see also https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/issues/6144, and https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/8970. I myself have encountered various differences between windows terminal, macOS' default terminal app, GNOME terminal, etc. and I can empathize that these issues are a pain when working on projects that benefit from consistency in these areas.

---

Note: At the time of the posting of the above question, this wasn't a thing, but be aware that since VS Code 1.88, rescaling of overlapping glyphs in the terminal is a thing. See [related release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_88#_rescaling-overlapping-glyph-in-the-terminal).

Comment: terminals tend to have problems with large swathes of Unicode, not just emoji.