# On vscode terminal (only on macOS) powerline glyphs spacing is off

Tags: visual-studio-code

On VS Code terminal (for macOS) powerline glyphs don't seem to introduce the correct spacing and the next character is rendered on top of the glyph. Some examples here:

[image]

correct behaviour in an actual terminal:

[image]

is this a bug? I tried various mode of GPU acceleration but it doesn't seem to make a difference. I also tested various Nerd fonts but they all have the same issue. The same config works fine on Linux.

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/q/76195909/11107541 help?

Comment: @starball that thread related but unfortunately doesn't suggest a solution

Comment: calls to mind also https://stackoverflow.com/q/76958870/11107541